# conversion error in c program from s64 to double?

Tags: c, linux, types, double, signed

In kernel : I am reading the time value as type `extern s64 Latency;`

In user space :

```
extern double latency;
//fp is reading the kernel value (i.e Latency)
fscanf (fp,"%lf", latency);
```

If I read s64 from kernel as double in the user space. Is there possibility of data loss ??
which data type should I use to get the complete value ??

Comment: A signed 64-bit integer type?

Comment: Use `long long` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Yes, there will definitely be data loss.

Think about it, both a signed 64 bit integer (`s64`) and a `double` has 64 bits of storage. But whereas the s64 only concerns itself with integers, a `double` can also represent fractions. To do that it needs to utilize some of the bits for this information, so there is no way that it can also represent the full range of 64 bit integers.

You should use `int64_t` from your toolchain's `stdint.h`.

Comment: thank you!! what is the format specifier for int64_t ?? can i send send int64_t value to A_uint64 on the other side (i.e.client) ??

Comment: I know the format specifier but dont knwo about: can i send int64_t value ti the A_uint64 on the other side ??

Comment: "inttypes.h" has the necessary macros for fixed width integer types, in particular `SCNd64` for use in `scanf` and friends.

Comment: @user3615655 If you know for a fact that the value i greater than or equal to zero, you can safely cast it to an uint64_t. Though, I don't understand why you wouldn't just keep the int64_t representation.

Comment: client side as : UBYTE,
SBYTE,
UWORD, SWORD, ULONG, SLONG,
A_UINT64, A_INT64,
FLOAT32_IEEE,
FLOAT64_IEEE : which one shall i use on the client side ??

Comment: never seen those typedefs, but I would guess A_INT64. You want an signed 64 bit integer (`long long` on many systems)