# is it possible to read s64 value from uint32?

Tags: c++, c, types, casting

code :

```
s64 end_time;
struct timespec ts;
getrawmonotonic(&ts);
end_time = timespec_to_ns(&ts);
```

How to remove the first three bytes from end_time and last one byte from it?? I want to store it in a uint32. could someone tell me how to do that??

```
uint32 latency;
fscanf(fp, "%lu\n", latency);  //fp  is reading the end_time and storing in latency.
latency = (uint32) (latency >> 8) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

after reading the s64 value from uint32. I am reading only 4bytes from that. 
Is it possible to read the s64 from uint32 ??

Comment: Perhaps `(end_time >> 8) & 0xffffffff`?

Comment: Neither `s64` nor `uint32` are standard C or C++ types.  I assume they are signed 64-bit and unsigned 32-bit integers, respectively, but with only the information given they could be anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [conversion error in c program from s64 to double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602887/conversion-error-in-c-program-from-s64-to-double)

Comment: the standard way since C99 is `int32_t` and `unsigned int64_t`

Comment: So, after you've thrown away the bottom 8 bits and the top 24 bits of a 64-bit value in order to store it in a 32 bit variable, you want to somehow magically recover those bits and get the full 64 bit value back? Not quite sure how that would work, but I suppose quantum computing might be involved...

Comment: duplicate of [this here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609388/how-to-remove-the-first-3-bytes-and-last-one-byte-from-s64-value)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Rather `uint32_t` and `int64_t`.

Comment: How do you read 64 bits from a 32 bit variable?  There are not enough bits.

Comment: You can extract the bits from a 32-bit variable and place them anywhere in a 64-bit variable.  The problem is that you cropped, cut, deleted and erased bits when you converted from the 64-bit to the 32-bit and these bits cannot be restored.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of bugs in this line:

```
fscanf(fp, "%lu\n", latency);
```

1. should be `&latency` (your version is a crashworthy logic error)
2. `uint32 latency` is not necessarily an `unsigned long`

I assume you want to read a number into latency which you expect to fit into a uint32?

The only portable way to do this is to use an ifstream.

This is because istream's operator>> will correctly overload for the non-standard uint32.

do it like this:

```
std::ifstream myfile("file_containing_values.txt");
uint32 latency;
myfile >> latency;  // correct overload is selected by the compiler.
```